# Detect change in window height and width with event listener

Tags: html, height, width, orientation, addeventlistener

Basically, I'm doing a matching game with tables of different orientation. If browser is resized to landscape or mobile device is turned, I make it a horizontal table. If portrait, then vertical table. I sorta need an event listener to detect if portrait or landscape.

Given 2 problems which can either be solved together or using separate code.

**Problem 1**

I'm viewing my page on a desktop and I resize my window such that width=768px and height=767px, then activate landscape mode.

Is there an **event listener** that determines whether it should display the portrait or landscape version of a page just simply by

```
if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
    portrait = true;
    /*display to portrait version of page*/
}
else {
    portrait = false;
    /*display to landscape version of page*/
}
```

or do I have to create a custom event listener and in that case how?

**Problem 2**

I'm viewing my page on a mobile device. When it detects it's in landscape mode by turning, activate landscape mode.

I believe this can be solved by

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
/*display landscape/portrait version*/
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are actually trying to do after you determine whether or not the user is in landscape mode or not there are several different implementations:

## Detect whether the user is Landscape or Portrait

```
function readDeviceOrientation() {          
    if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {
        // Landscape
    } else {
        // Portrait
    }
}
```

## Adjust styling using orientation media query

```
/* For portrait, we want the tool bar on top */
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
   #toolbar {
       width: 100%;
   }
}

/* For landscape, we want the tool bar stick on the left */
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    #toolbar {
        position: fixed;
        width: 2.65em;
        height: 100%;
    }

    p {
        margin-left: 2em;
    }

    li + li {
        margin-top: .5em;
    }
}
```

## Utilize jQuery

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {
        // Do Landscape
    } else {
        // Do Portrait
    }
};
```

## Listen for orientation change

```
screen.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
    console.log("The orientation of the screen is: " + screen.orientation);
});
```

Comment: I believe this only solves the second problem because "orientationchange" is related to mobile devices and when they turn clockwise/counterclockwise. How do you do event listening in jquery not css for when I manually resize my browser? Basically, I'm doing a matching game with tables. If browser is resized to landscape, I make it a horizontal table. If portrait, then vertical table. So I just need an event listener to detect if portrait or landscape.

Comment: @CHEWWWWWWWWWW I've added an example of binding a jQuery event on resize of the browser. On triggering of that event you can check if the device/browser is in landscape/portrait. Does that get you what you are looking for?

Comment: OMG. LIFE SAVER. I guess that's what I'm looking for! Thanks! Glad I learnt something new today!!